# How is this step completed?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

User [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did), did this step in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/805426/55235) to my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805260/joint-probability-generating-functions-help-please):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(zp)^kq^{n-k}=(q+pz)^n.$$

How is it done? Is it simply an identity, or something more?

Comment: Yes, google "Binomial Theorem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure why @Pedro didn't just post an answer, I guess I will (figured it'd be best to close this question).

Check out the [Binomial Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html).

The TL;DR version of this is that given some $n \in \mathbb{N}, a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}a^ib^{n-i}
$$
where
$$
\binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{(n-i)!i!}
$$
and $k!$ is defined recursively as:
$$
0! = 1, (k+1)! = (k+1)k!
$$